# Package dependencies cannot be resolved when installing codeblocks

Tags: dependencies, software-installation, code-blocks

Whenever I try to install codeblocks I get this error:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

```
 codeblocks : Depends: codeblocks-common (= 12.11-3) but it is not going to be installed
```

Answer (score 0):

Install codeblocks-common first, then install codeblocks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install  codeblocks-common first. You can do this either through Ubuntu Software Center or terminal using the following command

```
sudo apt-get install codeblocks-common
```

or you can handle the unmet dependecies with the following command

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```